# jquery address change not being triggered with different URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, jquery.address

I've hit a wall.  My scenario simply doesn't make sense.  I'm using the jquery address pluglin

Here is my issue:

A user enters a url with an argument like so:

```
http://localhost/#view_profile=1
```

The jquery address change function sees it fine and calls the appropriate method:

```
$.address.change(function(e) {

var urlAux = e.value.split('=');
var page   = urlAux[0];
var arg  = urlAux[1];

alert("page: " + page);
alert("arg: " + arg);

if (page == "/view_profile") {

    $.address.title("Profile");

    $('#main').load("view_profile.php?id=" + arg, function () { 
    alert("FUNCTION CALLED");
    });
}
....
```

Now, here's my issue; a user enters a new URL like so:

```
http://localhost/#view_profile=2
```

The address change is triggered but it never gets inside my if block.  If I enter the same address a second time it does trigger the code in my if block.

Is this a known issue or does it have something to do with page caching somehow?

output from first URL:

```
page: /view_profile
arg: 1
FUNCTION CALLED
```

output from second URL:

```
page: /view_profile
arg: 2
**** Why is the if block not being triggered? ***
```

output from second URL (agian):

```
page: /view_profile
arg: 2
FUNCTION CALLED
```

I'm stumped...

Comment: try alert(page == "/view_profile") just before the if statement ... or put another alert inside your block, at the beginning... perhaps the problem is not at the if statement